# Re-rendering a ReactJS component hangs browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been experimenting with creating a component based UI using ReactJS, versus my usual slapdash approach of a million global functions, variables and non-reusable markup. So far I really like React but I've hit a stumbling block.

Consider the following component layout

```
EventView
  EventViewSidebar
    EventViewList
      EventViewListRow
  EventViewDetail
```

In this layout, multiple occurrences of `EventViewListRow` are present for each unique key. Clicking an instance of `EventViewListRow` should update `EventViewDetail` with the details of that item.

This is the `render` function for the top level `EventView` component:

```
render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="event-view row-fluid">

          <div className="event-view__sidebar col-md-4">
            <EventViewSidebar projectId={this.state.projectId} />
          </div>

          <div className="event-view__content col-md-8" id="eventDetail">

          </div>

      </div>
    );
}
```

And this is the `EventViewDetail` component

```
var EventViewDetail = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return { eventId: 0 };
    },

    render: function () {
        if (this.state.eventId === 0) {
            return (<h3>Nothing selected</h3>);
        }
        else {
            return (
          <div>
              {this.state.eventId}
          </div>
          );
        }
    }
});
```

For the updating of `EventViewDetail` when a `EventViewListRow` is clicked, I have the following event handler defined in `EventViewListRow`

```
handleClick: function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    React.render(
            React.createElement(EventViewDetail, { eventId: this.props.id }),
              document.getElementById("eventDetail")
            ).setState({ eventId: this.props.id });

},
```

This all seems to be working fine (with the exception of the `setState` call above which I had to add otherwise clicking a different `EventViewListRow` didn't seem to have any effect - no doubt that's my first problem). The actual critical problem is that if I add default html to the `eventDetail` div defined in `EventView` then when I click the link in `EventViewListRow`, the following message is displayed in the console and the browser hangs.

> Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server:
>
> (client) <h3 data-reactid=".0">Nothing selected
>
> (server) <h3 data-reactid=".0.1.0">Select an even

Once the browser tab (Chrome 43) has hung, I have to terminate it using Task Manager.

Originally, I was calling an instance of the `EventViewDetail` directly, for example

```
          <div className="event-view__content col-md-8" id="eventDetail">
            <EventViewDetail />
          </div>
```

but it also hangs if I just use vanilla HTML

```
          <div className="event-view__content col-md-8" id="eventDetail">
            <h3>Select an event to view</h3>
          </div>
```

Clearly I'm doing something very wrong, but I'm somewhat unfamiliar with React so I don't know what that is. I read that I'm suppose to have state on the top level `EventView` component, but I don't have access to that and React doesn't seem to offer the ability to go back up the component chain. Unless you are supposed to pass the `EventView` instance as a property to each child component?

Oh, I should also add - I also tried removing the `setState` call from the `EventViewListRow` click handler in case that was the cause, but it had no effect.

Can anyone offer any advice on what it is I'm doing wrong. Should `EventView` have all the state for the child components, and if so, how do I reference the parent from a nested child component - do I have to pass the instance of `EventView` as a prop to every single child?

Sorry if these are idiot questions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not call React.render in the handleClick function. Just call this.setState and React will automatically render again.

Comment: I couldn't call `this.setState` as in that case `this` refers to the `EventViewListRow` which doesn't actually have state. I've just refactored the whole chain to pass the root `EventView` down so each component has it as a prop, and all state comes from `EventView`. Cautiously optimistic, as this looks to be working nicely - no hang and no warnings.

Comment: In the end, I resolved the hang by reworking my component chain so the children get passed a reference to the parent. The children then call methods on the parent which in turn adjust state and thus re-render the components. So although I already suspected this was probably the way to go, I'll mark this as the answer anyway - and besides, what Mark said is right.